# How do I work with Redux/React in Kotlin.js?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, redux, kotlin-js

I want to work with [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)/[React](https://reactjs.org/) in [Kotlin.js](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/working-with-javascript.html), but I only found Redux/React libraries for Android (such as [redux-kotlin](https://github.com/pardom/redux-kotlin)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Kotlin/JS you don't need "libraries" in a usual sense, you just need to tell compiler how to work with React.
In order to do this, you should write a set of `external` declarations and may be annotate them with special JS platform annotations (it' much like writing `d.ts` file in TypeScript).
See these links: [JavaScript interop](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html), [Module systems](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html).

You can look at following project: [kotlin-wrappers](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers).
However, author claims it's in a very early stage.
Another useful project is [kotlin-fullstack-sample](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-fullstack-sample), which shows how to use React with Kotlin.

Also, you can generate React declarations for Kotlin using [ts2kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt) tool.
It's also a bit incomplete and does not always produce proper declarations, you'll have to manually fix errors.

Finally, you can fall back to [dynamic](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html) type.
It's the fastest option to start using React, but with dynamic you won't get any benefit from Kotlin type system.

Note that with Kotlin you can't use JSX.
You can use [type-safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) instead, for example, [kotlinx.html](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html) library.

Comment: I am aware that it's possible to write a React wrapper. But I would prefer not to do it myself. I would rather use a library like clojurescript's Re-frame or scala's Diode.

Comment: I ended up calling the react.js library directly. It means some work to write the interface, but Kotlin is very good at javascript interoperation.

Comment: This all has changed and now completely obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write type wrappers for redux:

```
external interface ReduxState
external class Store {
    @JsName("getState")
    fun getState(): ReduxState

    @JsName("dispatch")
    fun dispatch(action: dynamic)
}

@JsModule("redux")
@JsNonModule
external object Redux {
    @JsName("createStore")
    fun <ST : ReduxState> createStore(reducer: (ST, dynamic) -> ReduxState,
                                      initialState: ST,
                                      enhancer: (dynamic) -> ST = definedExternally)
            : Store

    @JsName("applyMiddleware")
    fun applyMiddleware(vararg middleware: () -> (dynamic) -> dynamic)
            : ((dynamic) -> Unit, () -> ReduxState) -> Unit

    @JsName("compose")
    fun compose(vararg funcs: dynamic): (dynamic) -> dynamic
}
```

And for react-redux

```
@file:JsModule("react-redux")

package ktypings.redux

import react.RClass
import react.RProps
import react.ReactElement


@JsName("connect")
external fun <P : RProps, ST : ReduxState> connect(
    mapStateToProps: ((ST, P) -> P)? = definedExternally,
    mapDispatchToProps: (((dynamic) -> Unit, P) -> P)? = definedExternally
): (Any) -> RClass<P>

@JsName("Provider")
external val Provider: RClass<ProviderProps>

external interface ProviderProps : RProps {
    var store: Any
}
```

in order to use them from your kotlin code.
You can see example project here https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/kotlin-react-redux-material